# C++ Constant preprocessor macros and templates

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c-preprocessor

So say I have the following very simple macro, along with a bit of code to output it:

```
#define SIMPLEHASH(STRING) STRING[1] + STRING[2] + STRING[3]
std::cout <<  SIMPLEHASH("Blah");
```

This outputs 309, and if you view the assembly you can see:

```
00131094  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (132050h)] 
0013109A  push        135h 
0013109F  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13203Ch)]
```

Where `135h` translates nicely into 309 decimal. Everything was compiled away to a constant.

---

Now, say you have a template class as such:

```
template<int X> class Printer{
public:
 void Print(){
  std::cout << X;
 }
};
```

Then the following will nicely print the number 32:

```
Printer<32> p;
p.Print();
```

---

Both these things work individually, the problem comes when you try to combine them:

```
#define SIMPLEHASH(STRING) STRING[1] + STRING[2] + STRING[3]
 Printer<SIMPLEHASH("Blah")> p;
 p.Print();
```

In visual studio this gives:

> 1>.\ShiftCompare.cpp(187) : error C2975: 'X' : invalid template argument for 'Printer', expected compile-time constant expression
>       1>        .\ShiftCompare.cpp(127) : see declaration of 'X'

Despite the fact that `SIMPLEHASH("Blah")` can be reduced to a constant at compile time, as seen in the first example.

So, what gives, is there a way to tell the compiler "evaluate this first"? are templates naturally "before" macros in preprocessor evaluation?

Does anyone see any way I can get these two to work together?

Comment: The preprocessor is a red herring. According to the language, `"Blah"[0]` isn't a constant expression; that's it. Just because your compiler happened to figure it out doesn't mean anything. (And this is the problem with taking implementation-specific results and assuming it's guaranteed by the language.)

Comment: To answer the "how can I get these two to work together?" part, it would be helpful if you could explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.  If you can't _literally_ get these two things to work together, you might be able to solve your problem by some other means.

Comment: Was trying to get a hashing function to work to create aliases (at compile time) for registration in a factory class. I was trying to give the classes that need to be registered a static (template class) member s.t. that member could register it's owning class when it's constructor was called (being static, immediately on code load). The obvious other way is to use globals rather than static members, and that works fine, I just wanted to see if there was a way that didn't leave globals flying around in the namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are evaluated before the source is fully parsed and preprocessing has nothing at all to do with templates.

The problem is that the template argument with which you instantiate `Printer` must be a constant expression and you cannot use a string literal in a constant expression.